# php-openid Example server | Openid Server

Tags: openid, janrain, openid-provider

I've been scouring through the web looking for a good setup on a openID server provider. Everything I come across requires a lot of additional setup... Far above what I know to do right now. I'm trying to learn it all, but its been a difficult process being thrown into the middle of it without a whole lot of documentation.

So, with that being said, I've got all the files for the Janrain php-openID. I've got the example server laid out & set up my config.php.

I look through the config.php and it complains about not having a DB.php... I see it references it in the code, but I have no idea how the class is setup in the phantom "DB.php". There isn't a file in the git dist. of what I have, anyone have any ideas?

Or maybe, is there any easier way to setup a openID provider that uses MySQL w/o wildcard subdomains?

Thanks for any help!